# perl6 grammar actions: unable to make anything if not using $/

Tags: match, readonly, signature, assign, raku

I wrote a test program, and now it seems that if I don't use `$/` in a 
method signature because I have to use .match inside the method, I can no long make anything. What did I do wrong?

A further question is that if `.match` sets `$/`, and `$/` is read-only, then I cannot have `$/` in the signature of a method that contains a `.match` statement, and I cannot have more than one `.match` inside the method because each `.match` will try to set the read-only `$/`. This will be very awkward to program.

Here is the test program with only one `.match` statement inside and the results:

## The test program:

```perl6
grammar test {
    regex TOP   { <foo><bar> }
    regex foo   { :i \s* foo \s* }
    regex bar   { :i \s  bar \s* }
}

class actTest {
    method foo ($x) {              # program fails if I use $/ in signature
      print "1 "; say $x;          # how to combine the 2 and show $x as match?
      print "2 "; say $x.WHAT;
      my $newStr = $x.Str;
      print "3 "; say $newStr;
      my $newMatch 
         = $newStr.match(/:i(f)(oo)/); # adverb cannot be outside?
      print "4 "; say $newMatch.WHAT;
      print "5 "; say $newMatch;
      print "6 "; say $/;
      my $oo = $newMatch[1].Str;
      print "10 "; say $oo;
      my $f = $newMatch[0].Str;
      print "11 "; say $f;
      my $result = $oo ~ $f;
      print "12 "; say $result;
      make $result;                # now I cannot make anything; huh???
    }
    method TOP ($/) { 
      print "8 "; say $<bar>;
      print "9 "; say $<foo>.made; # failed, method 'foo' makes nothing
      make $<bar> ~ $<foo>.made; 
    }
}

my $m = test.parse("Foo bar", actions => actTest.new);
print "7 "; say $m;
```

## And the results:

```
1 ｢Foo ｣
2 (Match)
3 Foo 
4 (Match)
5 ｢Foo｣
 0 => ｢F｣
 1 => ｢oo｣
6 ｢Foo｣
 0 => ｢F｣
 1 => ｢oo｣
10 oo
 11 F
 12 ooF
1 ｢Foo｣
2 (Match)
3 Foo
4 (Match)
5 ｢Foo｣
 0 => ｢F｣
 1 => ｢oo｣
6 ｢Foo｣
 0 => ｢F｣
 1 => ｢oo｣
10 oo
11 F
12 ooF
8 ｢ bar｣
9 (Any)
Use of uninitialized value of type Any in string context.
Methods .^name, .perl, .gist, or .say can be used to stringify it to
something meaningful.
in method TOP at matchTest.pl line 28
7 ｢Foo bar｣
 foo => ｢Foo｣
 bar => ｢ bar｣
```

Comment: It might be a bug that you can't use `.match( :i, /…/ )`, or you have to use `.match( rx :i /…/ )` ( which if that is the case there should be a warning if you try the former ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1) How to `make` without `$/`

`make ...` is just a shortcut for `$/.make(...)`.

If you want to affect a different `Match` object than the one stored in `$/`, you have to use the method form directly, i.e. in your case `$x.make($result)`.

#### 2) When and why `$/` is read-only

By default, `$/` is bound to a normal item container (like a variable declared with `my`), i.e. *not* read-only. So there shouldn't be any problem with using the `.match` method multiple times in a routine.

It's only when you explicitly declare `$/` as a parameter in a routine signature, that `$/` will be bound directly to the `Match` object passed to that routine (not wrapped in an item container), and will thus be read-only inside the routine – because that's how normal signature binding works.

You could use the `is copy` trait to override the normal read-only parameter binding, and force `$/` to be a mutable item container inside the routine:

```
method foo ($/ is copy) { ... }
```

This way, using `.match` inside the routine would work, and would store a new `Match` object in `$/`. But then you wouldn't have access to the original `Match` object passed to the routine anymore, and thus couldn't affect it with `make`. So for an action method that needs to use `.match`, using a custom parameter name like you did is the way to go.